# How do you create the hash of a folder in C#?

Tags: c#, security

I need to create the hash for a folder that contains some files. I've already done this task for each of the files, but I'm searching for a way to create one hash for all files in a folder. Any ideas on how to do that?

(Of course I can create the hash for each file and concatenate it to some big hash but it's not a way I like)

Answer (score 40):

This hashes all file (relative) paths and contents, and correctly handles file ordering.

And it's quick - like 30ms for a 4MB directory.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

public static string CreateMd5ForFolder(string path)
{
    // assuming you want to include nested folders
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();

    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

    for(int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        string file = files[i];
        
        // hash path
        string relativePath = file.Substring(path.Length + 1);
        byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
        md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);
        
        // hash contents
        byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        if (i == files.Count - 1)
            md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
        else
            md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
    }
    
    return BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Beware FIPS compliance if you ever deploy this to a server with a Local Security Policy that enforces FIPS compliance

Comment: @SkeetJon the technique is the same for any crypto algorithm so you could just substitute SHA for FIPS machines.

Comment: Careful on the search pattern - should be "\*" instead of "\*.\*"

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` could prove this method to be very memory intensive.

Comment: In your method, we will get different hashes if file system returns same files in different ordering.

Comment: iRumba - it sorts files by path (`OrderBy...`)

Answer (score 20):

Dunc's answer works well; however, it does not handle an empty directory. The code below returns the MD5 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' (the MD5 for a 0 length character stream) for an empty directory.

```
public static string CreateDirectoryMd5(string srcPath)
{
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(srcPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderBy(p => p).ToArray();

    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
        {
            // hash path
            byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filePath);
            md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

            // hash contents
            byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes, 0);
        }

        //Handles empty filePaths case
        md5.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);

        return BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use this version, you will want to truncate `filePath` to a relative path to create `pathBytes` with.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that uses streaming to avoid memory and latency issues.

By default the file paths are included in the hashing, which will factor not only the data in the files, but the file system entries themselves, which avoids hash collisions. This post is tagged `security`, so this ought to be important.

Finally, this solution puts you in control of the hashing algorithm, which files get hashed, and in what order.

```
public static class HashAlgorithmExtensions
{
    public static async Task<byte[]> ComputeHashAsync(this HashAlgorithm alg, IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, bool includePaths = true)
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(Stream.Null, alg, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (includePaths)
                {
                    var pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.FullName);
                    cs.Write(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length);
                }

                using (var fs = file.OpenRead())
                    await fs.CopyToAsync(cs);
            }

            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        }

        return alg.Hash;
    }
}
```

An example that hashes all the files in a folder:

```
async Task<byte[]> HashFolder(DirectoryInfo folder, string searchPattern = "*", SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
{
    using(var alg = MD5.Create())
        return await alg.ComputeHashAsync(folder.EnumerateFiles(searchPattern, searchOption));
}
```

Comment: In addition, I would recommend sorting the file names and using `Path.GetRelativePath(folder, file.FullName)` so the hash is stable even if the file are in a different folder location.

Comment: Agreed that `files` could use to be sorted before hashing. However, `Path.GetRelativePath` is found only in netcore. Sorting on the full path of the file should do the trick. For directories with many entries, special care should be given so that sorting isn't too expensive. There are ways of producing a deterministic enumeration of files without sorting the entire sequence.

Comment: Be warned that FileStream.CopyToAsync() was introduced in NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 7):

Create tarball of files, hash the tarball.

```
> tar cf hashes *.abc
> md5sum hashes
```

Or hash the individual files and pipe output into hash command.

```
> md5sum *.abc | md5sum
```

Edit: both approaches above do not sort the files so may return different hash for each invocation, depending upon how the shell expands asterisks.

Comment: This is the only answer that also takes into account *all* meta information like dates, access rights , uids, guid , ...

Answer (score 4):

If you already have hashes for all the files, just sort the hashes alphabetically, concatenate them and hash them again to create an uber hash.

Comment: the catch with this is you can have filename changes and still get the same hash - maybe what you want, maybe not

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate filenames and files content in one big string and hash that, or do the hashing in chunks for performance.

Sure you need to take few things into account:

- You need to sort files by name, so you don't get two different hashes in case files order changes.
- Using this method you only take the filenames and content into account. if the filename doesn't count you may sort by content first then hash, if more attributes (ctime/mtime/hidden/archived..) matters, include them in the to-be-hashed string.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The string can be really big, so i will need to divide it on chunks, just thinking how to do it correctly.

Comment: I remember C# hashers had a function to feed them with chunks, and finally you can ask to get the final hash, not sure what these functions/classes were. With them you can sort your input the way you like in memory, then loop files and load chunks into few hundred KBs and feed it to the hasher, this way you don't need much memory but still, will take some time for hashing, which is something you can't get rid of.

Comment: This could cause memory related issues.

Answer (score -1):

Quick and Dirty folder hash that does not go down to suborders or read binary data.  It is based on file and sub-folder names.

```
Public Function GetFolderHash(ByVal sFolder As String) As String
    Dim oFiles As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sFolder).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Count).ToList()
    Dim oFolders As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sFolder).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Count).ToList()
    oFiles.AddRange(oFolders)

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then
        Return ""
    End If

    Dim oDM5 As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()
    For i As Integer = 0 To oFiles.Count - 1
        Dim sFile As String = oFiles(i)
        Dim sRelativePath As String = sFile.Substring(sFolder.Length + 1)
        Dim oPathBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sRelativePath.ToLower())

        If i = oFiles.Count - 1 Then
            oDM5.TransformFinalBlock(oPathBytes, 0, oPathBytes.Length)
        Else
            oDM5.TransformBlock(oPathBytes, 0, oPathBytes.Length, oPathBytes, 0)
        End If
    Next

    Return BitConverter.ToString(oDM5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower()
End Function
```