# How to set one md5 hash to multiple files

Tags: hash, md5

how can I set one md5 hash to multiple .ps files?

I know how to change md5 hash, but no idea how to set it to value which I would like to have.

Answer (score 1):

To create two files with the same md5 hash you can have a look here https://natmchugh.blogspot.co.za/2014/10/how-i-made-two-php-files-with-same-md5.html?m=1 .  The tricky part may be getting them to remain as valid PS files. In the example the author takes advantage of Pups language to add the differing text in such a way the syntax remains correct. Perhaps in a PS text section. Also have a look at https://natmchugh.blogspot.co.za/2015/05/how-to-make-two-binaries-with-same-md5.html?m=1

However usually you do not set the md5 hash but generate it from a file. This allows the recipient of the file to confirm it has not been corrupted by generating the md5 hash on their end and comparing with the one you gave them. If you are looking to generate one md5 hash for multiple files you could

1. Compress the files and generate the md5 hash from that file
2. Generate multiple md5 hashes and join them using an algorithm that always ensures the same value is produced from the hashes each time. For example concatenate the hashes or create an md5 hash of all the md5 hashes. The downside is whoever will use the hashes will also need to know the algorithm.

Have a look at [Combine MD5 hashes of multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677304/combine-md5-hashes-of-multiple-files)

Comment: Or form other side. How to create two different files with the same hash

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to achieve? Why do you need 2 files with the same hash?

Comment: For having two postscript files with the same hash

Comment: I have updated the answer to be relevant to the question

Comment: So it will bee pretty tricky because this files, are really long, and a lot of longer than files in your, example with php. Here are the files:

https://paste.ofcode.org/v8cyzbrVzxpdhUsYfnYfGv
https://paste.ofcode.org/YMUfHj86D3gfcwUYD9kKnY

Comment: So the question now is, where i should add something to have the same hashes