# How would I hash a folder using SHA1

Tags: c#, hash

Is there a way to use SHA1 to hash a folder with all of the contents within it? I am able to do this using MD5 but am afraid of the collisions MD5 suffers from. I am trying to build an app that checks local files to see if they match an online version using hashes.

Here is the code I am using with MD5:

```
var path = leftCheckTextbox.Text;
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .OrderBy(p => p).ToList();

MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
{
    string file = files[i];

    string relativePath = file.Substring(path.Length + 1);
    byte[] pathBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(relativePath.ToLower());
    md5.TransformBlock(pathBytes, 0, pathBytes.Length, pathBytes, 0);

    byte[] contentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    if (i == files.Count - 1)
        md5.TransformFinalBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length);
    else
        md5.TransformBlock(contentBytes, 0, contentBytes.Length, contentBytes,0);
}

leftHash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.Hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```

Comment: Do you want a single hash for the entire folder?  I don't know if there's a standard way to do that, but could you consider zipping everything and then hashing that single file instead?

Comment: If you are able to do this with MD5, why not with SHA1?

Comment: Do you intend to include (a) metadata (which?) (b) object data (c) both?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth this will likely include metadata that changes independent of the zipped objects thus rendering the checksum useless (a simple repeat test confirmed this on my box) (GNU `cpio -o` however produces consistent checksums)

Comment: @sehe: Yes, I guess it depends on the use-case.  If it's "I want to download a bunch of stuff from the web, and ensure it's the same at my end", then zipping (at the website end) and hashing makes sense.  If the files have come from somewhere arbitrary, then you're probably right.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth My point is if you zip+digest from a folder, and then do the exact same thing again, **on the same source**, it will not yield the same thing (it's not referentially transparent/deterministic)

Comment: @sehe: Yes I understand that ;)  What I'm suggesting is that if the OP is in control of both sides of the equation, then it might make sense to bundle up and present all the files as a single zip on the website end, then checking the hash of that *transferred* zip would be ok.  But who knows what the use-case is...

Comment: The following to folders with one file in them will have identical hashes: `name=xx, contents=x; name=x, contents=xx`. That's a bug.

Comment: Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15683147/70345

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change all `MD5` to `SHA1` in your source code.

Comment: I feel that this is the only sensible answer for the question as it stands.