# Is there anyway to know that new files added to a folder in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there anyway  to know that new files added to a folder in c# I can't use lastAccessTime and LastWriteTime and also I can't check if the size of the folder is changed because same size  deleted files cause problems with size. So is there anyway to check a new file  is added to a folder or not in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a `FileSystemWatcher`, which provides events to notify you of FileSystem changes. Example:

```
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = pathToWatch;

    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Have a look at the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

You can also set filters to watch only files, certain filenames etc.

Think carefully about the events you need to handle. If you watch created files, you probably want to handle deleted files as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and respond to each change in the folder.

Because the events can be quite confusing (some programs overwrite a file, others delete first and then create etc.) it might be usefull to create a custom way of tracking changes.

E.g., you could create a hash of each file and compare the old and new hash every change or every 5 minutes or so. This way you can decide yourself what should cause the hash to change.

See: [Creating hash for folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625658/creating-hash-for-folder) for an example.