# Incremental update of hash for folder

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I create a hash for a folder X with lots of files (and subfolders with files..) in it with the following method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349703/4752807

This takes about 30 seconds for the large amount of files in that folders.
Because the files can change frequently, this is too long.

So I came up with the idea to calculate the hash for each folder and each file and store them in a cache dictionary (`Dictionary<string, string> _hashCache`).
Then add a `FileSystemWatcher` for the folder X to get notified when a file is changed -> then only recalculate the hash for the changed file and update the parent folders hash recursivly.

But the problem now is: How can I use the hashes in my `_hashCache` dictionary to calculate the hash of the parent folder?

I already thought of something like the following: `hashOfFolder = md5(hashOfFile1 + hashOfFile2 + hashOfSubFolder1 + ...)` (assuming that the files are ordered).

Is this a correct way to calculate a hash for the folder?

Comment: Seems like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well.. I want to reduce the time it takes to calculate the hash of the folder so that there is an (almost) always up to date hash available for the folder.

We replicate this folder to some other servers and we need to check if all folders on all servers contain the same files with the same content.